# `django.request` logger not logging 4xx and 5xx responses from views

Tags: python, django, logging

I am trying to log all 4xx and 5xx responses with the `django.request` logger but this is only working when an exception is raised or a URL is not matched in the urlconf.

My `settings.py` is as follows:

```
import logging.config

LOGGING_CONFIG = None

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': "logfile",
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    },
}
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

If I have a view which returns a 4xx or 5xx status like this:

```
def test500(request):
    return HttpResponse("error", status=500)
```

Then nothing is logged. However if my view raises an exception like this then an exception is correctly logged:

```
def testcrash(request):
    print 1/0 # server will respond with 500
```

Is this the expected behaviour of `django.request` logger? What is the best way to log 5xx and 4xx responses returned by my views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this issue myself some time ago. Here is what happens:

- `500` errors are only logged if they are the result of an uncaught exception. If you set a `500` status manually then it will not be logged. Here's the [relevant part of the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/40b69607c751c4afa453edfd41d2ed155e58187e/django/core/handlers/base.py#L264) - as you can see that piece of logging happens inside a `handle_uncaught_exception` method.
- The behaviour for `404` responses is currently the same - only uncaught `Http404` responses are logged. **However**, this has changed in Django 1.10. See my [comment on this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26504#comment:4):

  > I just want to note that this change has altered the behaviour of Django's 404 logging somewhat.
  >
  > Previously, Django would only log a 404 if a `Http404` exception bubbled up to the core handler (and not if a view/middleware caught the exception and returned a response, regardless of whether that response was still a 404).
  >
  > Now, it will log all 404 responses regardless of how they were generated. This seems better to me but there may be applications that were relying on the previous behaviour.

  So from Django 1.10 onwards all `404` responses will get logged. It seems a bit inconsistent to me.
- Other `4xx` responses are only logged if the corresponding exception is raised. `400` exceptions are logged to `django.security` and not to `django.request.`

To answer your other question - what is the best way to consistently log this stuff? - the most reliable approach I have found is to write your own middleware which checks the status of all responses and does its own logging.

Edit: I've [created a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26688) that tries to address some of these inconsistencies in Django. The issue is fixed in Django 2.1.

Answer (score -1):

If you only need to see the errors and you are using apache2.4 server, you can find it at /var/log/apache2/error.log

The access log can be found at /var/log/apache2/access.log